# Centering custom view inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a cardview item:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="190dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grade"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="30dp" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And a layout containing a RecyclerView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/tb">
    </include>
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/grade_list"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#263238"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have an adapter which populates the RecyclerView with the cardview items. However, they are not being centered. Rather, they seem to be aligning to the left of my view. I have tried several solutions including using the following code in my OnCreate method of my RecyclerView's activity:

```
gradeList = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.grade_list);
    LinearLayoutManager lm = new    LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    lm.setOrientation(lm.VERTICAL);
    gradeList.setLayoutManager(lm);
    gradeList.setAdapter(new RecyclerAdapter(gradeData));
    gradeList.addItemDecoration(new RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

        @Override
        public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
            int totalWidth = parent.getWidth();
            int maxCardWidth = getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.card_width);
            int sidePadding = (totalWidth - maxCardWidth) / 2;
            sidePadding = Math.max(0, sidePadding);
            outRect.set(0,sidePadding,0,sidePadding);
        }
    });
```

However, nothing seems to be working.

EDIT: When using a layout as the root of my Card item:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the support library at least, the card view layout is embedded in a `FrameLayout` and this one is the culprit for your problems.

Since you can't mess with it in a clean way, I would suggest embedding your `CardView` in another layout where you have `width=match_parent` and its contents are centered. I tried with `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        ...
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this but the thing is the linear layouts edge is visible

Comment: What do you mean by that? A layout does not have any visible parts/edges unless you set it yourself. Could you share a screenshot, pls? - to make me understand.

Comment: alright I added a screenshot. You can see the edge right under the Card shadows

Comment: Oh, I see, it's not so much that the edge is visible, but the CardView does not fit into the linear layout, because of its shadow. There's no top or bottom margin between the card and the layout (in xml) and I assume that the one computed in the decorator is just too small for the elevation set on the card. Keep in mind also that on Lollipop+, the shadow extends the size of the card, while on Lollipop- the shadow takes away from the size of the device. You could just change the margins on the card view from 0dp to something else and see what plays nice for the elevation you have on the card.

Comment: oh I understand so essentially the fix is changing the layout margin.. thanks for the responses

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're talking about the card items not being centered. If so, I would suggest using a TableLayout and setting stretchColumn=0. This makes it so the card item is in the center and only column of your Recycler View. 
So in your case, just wrap your Recycler View with the TableLayout and TableRow. Here is an example of the code I'm using in my current Recycler View Layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="your_context"
    android:id="@+id/dataStructuresView"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="0">
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: unfortunately, this did not work for me. My card items are still aligning to the left of my layout.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a problem with cards clipping. See where they have a straight line cutting the shadow below the card ... Add 

`android:clipToPadding="false"
android:clipChildren="false"`

in your layout :)